# Google Maps v3: check if point exists in polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I am looking to find a way of checking if a point exists inside a polygon in Google Maps v3 (JavaScript). I've searched everywhere and the only solutions I have found so far have been to do with getting the bounds of the polygon, but the code shown seems to just create a rectangle and keeps expanding its surface area to include all relevant points.

By the way, the reason I can't just use a big square i.e. getting a polygons bounds, is that I have bordering polygons on the map and they can not expand into each other's territory.

EDIT
Following on from the reply below, I have tried implementing the example code using one of my existing polygons but it is just saying that it is not defined and I can't figure out why.

Here is my declaration:

```js
myCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(0.457301,-0.597382),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0.475153,-0.569916),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0.494379,-0.563049),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0.506738,-0.553436),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0.520470,-0.541077),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0.531456,-0.536957),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0.556174,-0.552063),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0.536949,-0.596008),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0.503991,-0.612488),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0.473780,-0.612488) ];

polyOptions = { 
    path: myCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#0000FF",
    fillOpacity: 0.6 };

var rightShoulderFront = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
rightShoulderFront.setMap(map);
```

and here is where I am checking for the point:

```js
var coordinate = selectedmarker.getPosition();
var isWithinPolygon = rightShoulderFront.containsLatLng(coordinate);
console.log(isWithinPolygon);
```

But it keeps coming up with the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: rightShoulderFront is not defined

Answer (score 51, accepted):

One algorithm to solve this is ray-casting. See an explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon).

And you can find code implementing this for the Google Maps JS API V3 [here](https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon).

HTH.

Comment: Do you have any running code? Maybe codepen or jsfiddle? Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

You can do this quite simply with Google maps geometry library.

First be sure to add the google maps geometry library.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
```

Then, define your polygon

```js
var rightShoulderFront = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: myCoordinates
        });
rightShoulderFront .setMap(map);
```

I'm going to add an event listener to handle a 'click' event, but you can adapt to fit your needs

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(rightShoulderFront , 'click', isWithinPoly);
```

Create a function to handle our click event an check if coordinate exists within polygon using Google's geometry library

```js
/** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
function isWithinPoly(event){
   var isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, this);
    console.log(isWithinPolygon);
}
```

Comment: Is there any limitation put by Google on usage of this method, 'containsLocation()'?

Answer (score 12):

You have a very good [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation) of `containsLocation()` method in Google Maps API documentation.

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look about the [Gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) library. It has a quite simple method about geofence.

Comment: Gmaps.js is awesome ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
var coordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(0.457301,-0.597382);//replace with your lat and lng values
var isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(coordinate, yourPolygon);
```

Dont forget to include the library in your googleapis script. [Read more...](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation)

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The example and implementation do not take into account that a polygon can cross the 180 degrees boundary.

The implementation does take it into account (implicitly) in the bounding box check, but the polygon check fails.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the same thing and working fine and its offline code I have written this code in PHP you can write it any programming language.

```
class pointLocation {
    var $pointOnVertex = true; // Check if the point sits exactly on one of the vertices?

    function pointLocation() {
    }

    function pointInPolygon($point, $polygon, $pointOnVertex = true) {
        $this->pointOnVertex = $pointOnVertex;

        // Transform string coordinates into arrays with x and y values
        $point = $this->pointStringToCoordinates($point);
        $vertices = array(); 
        foreach ($polygon as $vertex) {
            $vertices[] = $this->pointStringToCoordinates($vertex); 
        }

        // Check if the point sits exactly on a vertex
        if ($this->pointOnVertex == true and $this->pointOnVertex($point, $vertices) == true) {
            return "vertex";
        }

        // Check if the point is inside the polygon or on the boundary
        $intersections = 0; 
        $vertices_count = count($vertices);

        for ($i=1; $i < $vertices_count; $i++) {
            $vertex1 = $vertices[$i-1]; 
            $vertex2 = $vertices[$i];
            if ($vertex1['y'] == $vertex2['y'] and $vertex1['y'] == $point['y'] and $point['x'] > min($vertex1['x'], $vertex2['x']) and $point['x'] < max($vertex1['x'], $vertex2['x'])) { // Check if point is on an horizontal polygon boundary
                return "boundary";
            }
            if ($point['y'] > min($vertex1['y'], $vertex2['y']) and $point['y'] <= max($vertex1['y'], $vertex2['y']) and $point['x'] <= max($vertex1['x'], $vertex2['x']) and $vertex1['y'] != $vertex2['y']) { 
                $xinters = ($point['y'] - $vertex1['y']) * ($vertex2['x'] - $vertex1['x']) / ($vertex2['y'] - $vertex1['y']) + $vertex1['x']; 
                if ($xinters == $point['x']) { // Check if point is on the polygon boundary (other than horizontal)
                    return "boundary";
                }
                if ($vertex1['x'] == $vertex2['x'] || $point['x'] <= $xinters) {
                    $intersections++; 
                }
            } 
        } 
        // If the number of edges we passed through is odd, then it's in the polygon. 
        if ($intersections % 2 != 0) {
            return "inside";
        } else {
            return "outside";
        }
    }

    function pointOnVertex($point, $vertices) {
        foreach($vertices as $vertex) {
            if ($point == $vertex) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }

    function pointStringToCoordinates($pointString) {
        $coordinates = explode(" ", $pointString);
        return array("x" => $coordinates[0], "y" => $coordinates[1]);
    }

}

$pointLocation = new pointLocation();
$points = array("22.732965336387213 75.8609390258789");
$polygon = array("22.73549852921309 75.85424423217773","22.72346544538196 75.85561752319336","22.72346544538196 75.87175369262695","22.732332030848273 75.87295532226562","22.740406456758326 75.8686637878418","22.74198962160603 75.85407257080078");
echo '<pre>';
print_r($polygon);
// The last point's coordinates must be the same as the first one's, to "close the loop"
foreach($points as $key => $point) {
    echo "point " . ($key+1) . " ($point): " . $pointLocation->pointInPolygon($point, $polygon) . "<br>";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

I think google has solved it with this method of `containsLocation()`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation