# Google API: Notification when marker will be into shape

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-api-2

i am using google maps API V2 and i have geozones  like shape. now want get alert when unit(Simple Markers) will be into shape coordinats. how i can do this?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you post the code :D

Comment: i have no code bro. i think how i can solve this problem... i have only Google Map, Markers on Gmap and shapes.

Comment: I mean to say if you have the javascript  function post it, it makes easier to help you

Comment: no i have not js functions about that question...

Comment: ok then no problem so what you require is that whenever a marker is placed in the certain region then you should show the alert right?

Comment: yes if marker will pass into shape zone i want alert about that.

Comment: The API v2 is deprecated and will probably stop working completely after May 19, 2013. You should use API v3 instead

Comment: thanks but first i need resolve this problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function changeMarker(marker) {
            marker.setIcon("images/bluemarker.png");
        }
        var map;
        var infowindow;
        var info1;
        var triangleCoords = [];
        function InitializeMap() {
            var myOptions =
            {
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

            triangleCoords = [
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(20.874252, -80.190262),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
                                    new google.maps.LatLng(20.874252, -80.190262)
                             ];

            // Construct the polygon
            // Note that we don't specify an array or arrays, but instead just
            // a simple array of LatLngs in the paths property
            Triangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: triangleCoords,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                fillOpacity: 0.35
            });

            Triangle.setMap(map);

        }
        function markicons() {
            InitializeMap();
            var ltlng = [];
            var markers = [];
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(22.76, -79.28));
            ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(18.76, 83.30));
            map.setCenter(triangleCoords[0]);
            for (var i = 0; i < ltlng.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: ltlng[i],
                    draggable: true,
                    //icon: "images/greymarker.png",
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    title: "this is " + i + "marker"

                });

            }
        }
        window.onload = markicons;
    });

</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" >
        <h2>Multiple Markers :</h2>
            <div id="map-container"><div id="map"></div></div> 
</asp:Content>
```

There are 2 parts in your question

1. Construct a polygon and introduce some markers in the map
2. when ever it finds a marker in the area you have to alert
   so for 1 you can refer above js as the sample for 2 you can refer below discussion which already contains in this forum....

hope this helps:D

[google maps v3: check if point exists in polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522484/google-maps-v3-check-if-point-exists-in-polygon)