# Check if a point is inside a Polygon with the Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon

I am developing an application using the Google Maps API v3, and I'm struggling to know how to find out if an X coordinate is inside a polygon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps v3: check if point exists in polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522484/google-maps-v3-check-if-point-exists-in-polygon)

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [Geometry Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) of the Google Maps JS API. There's a function called `containsLocation` which tells you if a given LatLng is inside a **Polygon**. Note that it's a Polygon, not a Polyline. A Polyline is (as it says in the name) a line. So there is no such thing as a point being inside a polyline. You can check if a point is inside a Polygon with the `containsLocation` function.

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(somePoint, somePolygon)
```

Comment: But it's for JavaScript, How to do the same for iOS, with Objective C Google Maps SDk ??

Answer (score 4):

In iOS it can be done by using `GMSGeometryContainsLocation`

Just create a `GMSMutablePath`, then fill with vertexes of your polygon and test the point.

Example(**Swift 4.0**):

```
func isWithin(_ point: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
    let p = GMSMutablePath()
    p.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:30.02356126, longitude: -90.07047824))
    p.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:30.02501037, longitude: -90.0614231))
    p.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:30.03321034, longitude: -90.0617981))
    p.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:30.03192855, longitude: -90.07342815))
    return GMSGeometryContainsLocation(point, p, true)
}
```

Note: If the last param of `GMSGeometryContainsLocation` is set to true, the `GMSMutablePath` is composed of great circle segments, otherwise it's of rhumb (loxodromic) segments.