# Google maps: Route fencing

Tags: google-maps

I have a requirement of **tracking vehicles**. For which I have to perform **route tracking** as well (checking if a vehicle is moving at preselected route or not). Can you suggest the best way to do it?

A way which I can think of is getting a **polygon** covering route generated by `google directions`. This polygon may leave margin of about 50m around the route. I can get polyline from route suggested by google. A polygon enclosing the route leaving some (arbitrary) margin around the route may do the job.

Is it possible to do so using `Google Maps v3 Javascript APIs`? If you think the way I am thinking of is not appropriate, please suggest the most appropriate one.

Comment: Is it possible to do so using Google Maps v3 Javascript APIs? YES. look at this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: and this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522484/google-maps-v3-check-if-point-exists-in-polygon