# Calculate the intersection area of a circle and a polygon in Google Maps Javascript API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am drawing a circle on a layer which has a lot of polygons (from Maps Engine) on it and trying to get the area of the intersection between my circle and the polygon.

If i use the intersects method from Maps Engine, i am getting all the coordinates of the polygon, but not exactly getting the points where i cut the polygon with my circle.

There is an example image:

[image]

You can get the Radius from drawingManager like `circle.getRadius()` and the area of it, as everybody knows `circleArea=Math.PI*radius*radius`

And with the intersects method from Maps Engine `intersects=CIRCLE(center_lng center_lat, radius)`, then we can use the area of the all polygon area with computeArea method.

`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea();`

At the end actually i want only the intersection between the polygon and the circle.
Is there any other method that i can get the Intersection area between them?

Comment: A quick google search shows up this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522484/google-maps-v3-check-if-point-exists-in-polygon which brings me to this: https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon I suggest you calculate an array of points around the circle and use the above plugin to see if they're inside the polygon using a forloop. I know it's not an answer but I hope this helps

Comment: The [intersects geographic restriction](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/read#geographic_restrictions) doesn't do what you want.  Neither does the [ST_INTERSECTS Relationship function](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/read#relationship_functions).

Comment: Actually it is kind of a Weiler–Atherton clipping algorithm. Maybe this can help me more : [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/) Thanks for the advices!

Comment: You can [use the JSTS library to generate a polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037104/how-to-calculate-intersection-area-in-google-maps-api-with-jsts-library)
that represents the intersection area you want.