# How to calculate intersection area in Google Maps API with JSTS Library?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to calculate the area of the intersection between two triangles. 
I found out the [JSTS Topology Suite](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) has a [Geometry class](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/symbols/jsts.geom.Geometry.html) which a method [intersection()](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/symbols/jsts.geom.Geometry.html#intersection).
I tried it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbs2h59e/6/) and on my local computer but i am getting an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.
There is also an [example](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/examples/overlay.html) from JSTS. Here you can see the code. 
My code looks the same in JSFiddle:

```
var union = triangleCoords.union(secondTriangleCoords);
var intersection = triangleCoords.intersection(secondTriangleCoords);
console.log('Intersection ' + intersection);
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(intersection);
```

Is there a conversion that i should do also?

Comment: The jsts library doesn't add a union method to the Google Maps Polygon class.

Comment: The answer to this question [Google Maps Polygons self intersecting detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017463/google-maps-polygons-self-intersecting-detection/25019306#25019306) might be relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general answer is you need to convert the google.maps.Polygon objects into jsts.geom.Geometry objects, then run the union.  If you want to display the result on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map, then you need to convert the returned jsts.geom.Geometry object back into a google.maps.Polygon.

This code (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017463/google-maps-polygons-self-intersecting-detection/25019306#25019306)) converts a path into a jstsPolygon:

```
var coordinates = googleMaps2JTS(googlePolygonPath);
var geometryFactory = new jsts.geom.GeometryFactory();
var shell = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(coordinates);
var jstsPolygon = geometryFactory.createPolygon(shell);
```

Something like this:

```
var geometryFactory = new jsts.geom.GeometryFactory();

var trito = bermudaTriangle.getPath();
var tritoCoor = googleMaps2JTS(trito);
var shell = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(tritoCoor);

var trito2 = secondBermuda.getPath();
var tritoCoor2 = googleMaps2JTS(trito2);
var shell2 = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(tritoCoor2);

var jstsPolygon = geometryFactory.createPolygon(shell);
var jstsPolygon2 = geometryFactory.createPolygon(shell2);

var intersection = jstsPolygon.intersection(jstsPolygon2);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbs2h59e/14/)

To use the computeArea method on the result, though, you need to convert it back into an array or an MVCArray of google.maps.LatLng objects ([computeArea(path:Array.|MVCArray., radius?:number)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical))

Or you could use the [jsts.geom.Polygon.getArea] (http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/symbols/jsts.geom.Polygon.html#getArea) method.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbs2h59e/16/) with area of triangles, union and intersection using the jsts method.

Code to convert the results back to google.maps.LatLng and google.maps.Polygon objects:

```
var jsts2googleMaps = function (geometry) {
  var coordArray = geometry.getCoordinates();
  GMcoords = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < coordArray.length; i++) {
    GMcoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coordArray[i].x, coordArray[i].y));
  }
  return GMcoords;
}

var intersectionGMArray = jsts2googleMaps(intersection);
```

Then to get the area:

```
var intersectionGMarea = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(intersectionGMArray);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbs2h59e/18/)

Comment: Thank you very much! this is great! But i still don't get [Area Method from JSTS](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/symbols/jsts.geom.Polygon.html#getArea), what is it returning? In the documentation only mentioned that 'Returns the area of this Polygon'.
And can you please merge [with this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504068/how-to-show-the-intersecting-area-of-two-polygons-on-google-maps), i think they are the same
Thanks

Comment: The best I can tell (and I agree it isn't clear), the getArea method of JSTS returns the 2 dimensional area (so if you give it Lat/Lng coordinates the units would be degree^2, not but so useful), which is why I added the translation back to Google Maps objects in my answer, as the functions there return meters and square meters.