# What is the alternative to deprecated Google Maps Geofences

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Since [Google Maps Geofences](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tracks/geofences) is deprecated, what could be the other alternative to mark the geofences on a google map and check if coordinates are inside or outside of fence?

Comment: Maybe you should implement by yourself. This might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522484/google-maps-v3-check-if-point-exists-in-polygon

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Geofence is now only available on Android implementations. If you want to, you can checkout the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) on how you can implement it using Android.

Otherwise, I found this Google Maps Javascript implementation on [github](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/geofences.html) which uses polygons that acts like geofences. Maybe you can use this as a guide in building your application.